# Z-index modification on layer change (jquery plugin modification)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using the following jquery plugin news rotator for displaying several different news headlines:
http://landofcoder.com/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=372&task=view.download&cid=9

Quite a nice headliner, but it doesn't seem to modify z-index when you jump to different layers / stories and consequently the video that is embedded on layer 1 always activates, even if I click news stories or vides in other layers.  So, for example, if I move to another story and click the play button, the video on the 1st (top most) story activates vs the one I'm on.

I was hoping for an example of how to modify the script to facilitate also changing z-index on layer / story change.

I am guessing that the modification could be made in the `fxStart` function below the opacity shift within the `script.js` file, but I'm just not up to snuff on js yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the way I get around the white screen behind is to only animate the current layer. So when you want to fade to the next layer, you:
 1. Set the z-index of the current layer to a high number (say 3)
 2. Set the z-index of the next layer to a lower number (say 2) and set the opacity to 1
 3. Fade out the current layer only and that will reveal the next layer below. 
 4. Set a callback function on the current layer animation to reset z-indexes to their correct values so as to not mess up the next transition.

so adapting my last suggestion, I would recommend:

```
// accomodate your other issue
var $nextObj = $(this.slides).eq(index).css({zIndex:900, opacity:1});
$(currentObj).css({zIndex:1000}).stop().animate( {opacity:0}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing}, function(){ $(this).css({zIndex: 1}); $nextObj.css({zIndex: 2}); );
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense however it still creates a situation where the loader just spins ad infinitum.  Something's off there, but I've left the code in for you to glance at (lof-script.js).

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a website for this script to demonstrate or expose the api (doesn't seem to have any api) so this is a shot in the dark ... You should be able to change line 277 with these two lines:

```
$(currentObj).css({zIndex:2});
$(this.slides).eq(index).css({zIndex:3}).stop().animate( {opacity:1}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
```

The idea here is that before the animation begins you simply set the correct zIndex of the videos.

Again this is a shot in dark because I'm assuming 'currentObj' is the currently displayed object and '$(this.slides).eq(index)' is the next object underneath.

Comment: I ended up going with changing the transition type.  The z-index issue didn't seem to do the trick, likely due to flash in the mix from Wistia.  Using a horizontal scroller did the trick, but thanks anyway for the effort as you certainly offered insight.